# EMC ESRS stops working when it is VMotioned

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esx, storage-area-network, emc, vmotion

EMC is on site and told me:

> The ESRS SAN monitoring solution will cease to function if that host is VMotioned

In case anyone doesn't know, the ESRS is a dial home solution that works over IP.  An EMC SecureID is required to add or modify the list of devices that are monitored.  The ESRS software is installed on the customer premises.

**Question**

If ESRS truly fails to work, as the EMC engineer stated, and based on our customer experience, what is it within VMWare that is exposed to the virtualized host that allows this behavior to happen?

Comment: https://community.emc.com/thread/133274

Comment: @ewwhite I think "MAC" in that post is wrong as VMotion does not alter the Mac (and when cloning a VM the Mac can also be preserved), so most likely it is the DMI UUID as mentioned below instead. This seems to be a rather unpleasant DRM restriction.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the UUID changed. It is used when generating encryption certs/keys and used to verify the the gateway is running on the same sever and not a "hijacked" server (I'm guessing, of course).

From VMWares's KB: "[t]he UUID is based on the physical computer's identifier and the path to the virtual machine's configuration file. This UUID is generated when you power on or reset the virtual machine. As long as you do not move or copy the virtual machine to another location, the UUID remains constant."[1](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1541)

If you wish to troubleshoot this further I'd look at the ESRS logs for errors about cert/key errors. Also, collect the DMI output before and after migration and compare them. I've only used the Linux-based dmidecode tools but I'm sure there are similar tools for Windows.